# Why my state wouldn't change while using Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser() and useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm working on an AWS amplify project and I was trying to mange my App.js state with useEffect and Auth class which is provided by amplify.

So my goal is to check Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser() first thing when the user enters the App, and to update my state (isLogged userEmail) so I will be able to pass it to it's children components like NavBar.

I tried to do it in a few ways like useContext/using initialState outside the component, but it have not worked.

I can log the data but when I try to update my state it wouldn't work.
What would be the right approach to handle this state based on the Auth user?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Amplify, { Auth, Hub } from "aws-amplify";
import awsconfig from "./aws-exports";
import Layout from "./Layout";
import { AuthContext } from "./context/context";
Amplify.configure(awsconfig);

export default function App() {
  const [isLogged, updateIsLogged] = useState(false);
  const [userEmail, setUserEmail] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser().then((data) => {
      updateIsLogged(true);
      setUserEmail(data.attributes.email);
    });

    console.log("islogged : ", isLogged);
    console.log("email : ", userEmail);

    Hub.listen("auth", (data) => {
      const { payload } = data;
      console.log("new event has happend ", data);
      if (payload.event === "signIn") {
        updateIsLogged(true);
        setUserEmail(data.attributes.email);
        console.log("user has signed in");
      }
      if (payload.event === "signOut") {
        updateIsLogged(false);
        console.log("user has signed out");
      }
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <Layout isLogged={isLogged} userEmail={userEmail}>
      {" "}
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

Comment: you need to add a dependency array to the useEffect hook as a second argument, it tells it to watch that state. try adding the state you want to watch to the empty array at the end of your useEffect hook and see if that does it. `useEffect( () => { }, [isLogged])`

Comment: @HolyMoly I think he just wants to run it only once on mount. Which is what his code will currently do since he does have the empty `[]` as a dependency.

Comment: I did try to add them to the array but it still does not work